# hazelcast not equals predicate searching a collection attribute

Tags: hazelcast

I am using a hazelcast map to store an object very similar to the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
public class Organization
{
    public static final String MAP_NAME = "organizations";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "organizationId", unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    protected String organizationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organizationId")
    private Set<RecordKeeperConfig> recordKeeperConfigs;
}
```

And RecordKeeperConfig is defined like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recordKeeperConfig")
public class RecordKeeperConfig
{
    public static final String MAP_NAME = "recordKeeperConfig";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "recordKeeperConfigId", unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    protected String recordKeeperConfigId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @Column(name = "organizationId", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    protected String organizationId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type", length = 8)
    protected RecordKeeperType type;
}
```

Ultimately I want to get back a Set of all of the Organization objects where there is at least one RecordKeeperConfig. I tried using Predicate.notEqual("recordKeeperConfigs", null) but it produces the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot use NotEqualPredicate predicate with an array or a collection attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the logical operation as a transient method in your entity class. Then instead of the collection, construct the Hazelcast predicate on that:

Method:

```
@javax.persistence.Transient
public boolean isRecordKeeperConfigsNotEmpty() {
    return getRecordKeeperConfigs() != null && !getRecordKeeperConfigs().isEmpty();
}
```

Predicate:

```
EntryObject e = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
PredicateBuilder predicate = e.is("recordKeeperConfigsNotEmpty");
Collection<Organization> filteredOrganizations = organizationMap.values(predicate);
```